# React Navigation - conditional hide item in bottom navigation bar

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How to hide one of the item in the react-navigation bottom navigation bar based on some condition

> For Example : this.state.show == true

So far i had tried as below

```
const Main = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Home: {screen: HomeStack},
  CheckInOut:  this.state.show ? {screen: CheckStack} : null ,
  Attendance: {screen: AttendanceStack},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileStack},
},
```

Comment: please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58553998/6197968 I have implemented the same thing in my project. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Are you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to make condition where you'r rendering your  View.

You need to generate two Main View in first declare all the tabs, In second discard the one you don't want to render.

e.d

```
const FullManu = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Home: {screen: HomeStack},
  CheckInOut:  this.state.show ? {screen: CheckStack} : null ,
  Attendance: {screen: AttendanceStack},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileStack},
},


const HalfManu = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Home: {screen: HomeStack},
  Attendance: {screen: AttendanceStack},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileStack},
},
```

Now on your Main file import both these & render conditionally as:

```
render() {
     return(
         <View>
            {this.state.show ? <FullManu> : <HalfMenu>}
         </View>
     )
}
```

Comment: No other way to do it without generating two Main View?

Comment: Anyway I got this error when i use ur solution `This navigator has both navigation and container props, so it is unclear if it should own its own state. Remove props: "isLogin, dispatch" if the navigator should get its state from the navigation prop. If the navigator should maintain its own state, do not pass a navigation prop.`

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render tabs to hide any item.
This is basically the same solution as above but in different way of writing.

```
const AppNavigator = ()=> {

  let tabs
  if(show){
    tabs = (
      <>
        <AScreen />
        <BScreen />
        <CScreen />
      </>
    )
  }else{
    tabs = (
      <>
        <AScreen />
        <CScreen />
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
     {tabs}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )


}
```