# How to dynamically change the bottom tab navigator in React-Native?

Tags: android, react-native, stack-navigator

How can I change my Bottom-tab-navigator dynamically? In the bottom tab I am having Home and Settings.

I'm having two stack navigators i.e HomeStack and SettingsStack. In home stack, I am having details screen. when i moved from home to details screen,bottom tab will changed to profile and share?How to do dynamically in React-Native?
https://aboutreact.com/react-native-bottom-navigation-icon-from-local/

Above url is reference,when I click on details button in home,Bottom tab how to change dynamically?.

Comment: I have already answer this question, Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58553998/6197968

Comment: @Naresh Thanks for your reply,can you post the code.I am beginner in react native.